# Random array / matrix intitialisation in Fortran

Tags: random, matrix, fortran, fortran95

Is there a way to initialise a random array without using explicit do-loops?

Right now my random matrix initialisation looks like

```
program Main
    implicit none
    save

    integer :: seed, i, j
    real :: x
    character(100) :: option
    real, dimension(10,10) :: matrix

    if (iargc() > 0) then
        CALL GETARG(1,option)
        read(option,*) seed
    else
        seed = 1
    end if 

    call RANDOM_SEED(seed)

    do i=1,10
        do j=1,10
            call RANDOM_NUMBER(x)
            matrix(i,j) = x
        end do
    end do
end program
```

But if possible I'd like it to be more along the lines of an implied do-loop array initialisation:

```
program Main
    implicit none
    save

    integer :: seed
    character(100) :: option
    real, dimension(10,10) :: matrix

    if (iargc() > 0) then
        CALL GETARG(1,option)
        read(option,*) seed
    else
        seed = 5
    end if 

    call RANDOM_SEED(seed)

    matrix = reshape((/ ((call RANDOM_NUMBER()), i=1,100) /), shape(matrix))
end program
```

Is there any way something like this would be possible with Fortran 95?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Why not

`call RANDOM_NUMBER(matrix)`  ?

Comment: +1 Or, as one might otherwise put it, why not read the Fortran manual ?

Comment: Because this way future people can find the answer more easily through their favourite search engine.