# Generating an array of random numbers in the range of [-1, 1]

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am trying to generate random numbers in the range of [-1, 1] in Fortran in a 2D array. I know that in order to generate random numbers in the range of -1 and 1, I have to rescale the numbers to [0,2) but I am not getting how to fill matrix `x(10,10)` with `randomReal`. Here is the code

```
program random
implicit none
real :: rnd, randomReal
real, dimension (10,10) :: x
integer :: L, i
L = 10         ! length of sequence
do i = 1, L
  call random_number(rnd)
  randomReal = 2*rnd-1
  print *, "random real = ", randomReal


end do
       write(*,*) (x(L,L), L=1,10) ! assign random numbers to matrix x
       call random_number(x)
    end program random
```

Could anyone give me some suggestions on my problem?

Answer (score 4):

As per [Random array / matrix intitialisation in Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22636532/fortran-random-matrix-intitialisation/22637268#22637268) (did you read that?) you can do

```
 xmin = -1
 xmax =  1
 call random_number(x)
 x = xmin + (xmax-xmin)*x
```

BTW, the numbers will be from interval `[-1,1)`, not `[-1,1]`.