# Generate random real number between -1.5 and 1 in fortran

Tags: fortran

I'm just a beginner to fortran but I want to know how to generate a random real variable between -1.5 and 1

Comment: Ahh, good point - there must be a better duplicate somewhere ....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating an array of random numbers in the range of \[-1, 1\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42544397/generating-an-array-of-random-numbers-in-the-range-of-1-1)